# Weak convergence of stochastic processes sequence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ a sequence of stochastic processes in $ C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}^k)$. We suppose that $X_n \Rightarrow X$  in $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}^k)$.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^k$ a continuous function. We define :

$$Y_n = \int_0^1 f(X_s^n) \mathrm{d}s$$ and $$Y = \int_0^1 f(X_s) \mathrm{d}s$$

Show that $(X_n,Y_n) \Rightarrow (X,Y)$

**Attempt**

I try to show that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges to  $(X,Y)$ in the sense of finite marginal distributions, and that $(X_n,Y_n)$ is tight.

Convergence in the sense of finite marginal distributions

We know that $X_n \Rightarrow X$.

And because the function $f$ and the application $I$ from $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}^k)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle I(f) = \int_0^1 f(X_s) \mathrm{d}s$ are continuous, we have : $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$.

Tightness

Then $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are tight sequences, because they are weak convergent. Hence, $(X_n,Y_n)$ is also tight.

Then $(X_n,Y_n) \Rightarrow (X,Y)$

I am not sure of this answer. Any help ? Please.

Comment: doesn't $(X_n, Y_n) \to (X, Y)$ pointwise already?

Comment: Thanks I think we have only weak convergence for $X_n$ . I am not sure that this implies pointwise convergence

Comment: You said $X_n \to X$ in $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}^k$. Doesn't that mean $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$ for a.e. $\omega$?

Comment: I first wrote $X_n => X$ and it was modified. There are no hypothesis of pointwise convergence. I have to show that $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges weakly to $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Then in what sense does $X_n \to X$ here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$

Comment: We have $(X_n, Y_n) = (X_n, I(X_n)) \to (X, I(X))$ in distribution because $X_n \to X$ in distribution and the map $x \mapsto (x, I(x))$ is continuous.